# Why didn't my defined function work as expected?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this exchange rates data (365 rows and 163 columns)

[image]

This is the first 5 rows of 3 selected columns:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'],
                     'EUR': [0.636805, 0.637249, 0.637676, 0.642802, 0.643764],
                     'JPY': [89.564402, 89.217571, 88.275751, 89.122584, 90.270398], 
                     'USD': [0.680616, 0.680714, 0.676402, 0.681486, 0.681911]
                    })
```

and the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib widget

def subset_data(start_date, end_date, currency_1, currency_2):
    start_idx = df.index[df['Date'] == pd.to_datetime(start_date)].tolist()[0]
    end_idx = df.index[df['Date'] == pd.to_datetime(end_date)].tolist()[0]
    col1_idx = df.columns.get_loc(currency_1)
    col2_idx = df.columns.get_loc(currency_2)
    return df.iloc[start_idx:end_idx, [0, col1_idx, col2_idx]]

@widgets.interact(start_date=df['Date'].values, 
                  end_date=df['Date'].values,
                  currency_1=df.columns,
                  currency_2=df.columns)
           
def update(start_date='2023-01-01', end_date='2023-01-31', currency_1='USD', currency_2='JPY'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    data = subset_data(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, currency_1=currency_1, currency_2=currency_2) # THIS LINE OF CODE DIDN'T WORK AS EXPECTED
    print(data.head(2))
    ax.plot(data['Date'], data[currency_1], label=currency_1)
    ax.plot(data['Date'], data[currency_2], label=currency_2)
    ax.set_title('Exchange Rates of AUD Over Time')
    plt.xticks(fontsize=7, rotation=45, ha='right', rotation_mode="anchor")
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

However, when executing the code (in a jupyter cell), the function `subset_data` (enclosed within the function `update`) didn't work as expected, that is, it didn't slice the `df` (that contains the data for the whole year 2023) for the month of January only, as evidenced below

[image]

Only when I changed the `end_date` widget value (default at 1Jan2023) to a different date, then the code worked as expected, that is, it produced correct visuals.

[image]

Could someone please explain what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @tripleee. How should I let readers know the wrong and the correct outputs of the code?

Comment: Images of graphs obviously make sense, but the picture of the data we need to reproduce the problem is an unnecessary hurdle which you should fix.

Comment: I added a small sample data in the post. Hope that would be sufficient for reproducible purpose. Thanks.